# Array enviado via Json para Javascript chega nulo nele

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xampp

Tenho uma aplicação em que, um Javascript eu tneho uma função que realiza uma chamada Ajax para o arquivo .php tratar. O .php trata com a função **buscaConta(p)** assim: faz um SELECT no banco MySql (gerido via XAMPP e phpMyAdmin), pega o resultado dessa query, salva em um array e devolve para uma outra função Javascript (callBack), chamda **"formaCanvas(p)"**  no formato Json.
Só que o que eu recebo nessa minha função JS de callback é  [] .Que seria um array vazio correto? Isso na maioria das vezes. Somente na primeira vez que eu rodo a aplicação depois de carregada é que eu recebo o resultado correto nela: o númer de agência, de conta e de saldo. .Que seria um array vazio correto?

Só que não função **buscaConta()** do php, antes de mandar o resultado da query para a **formaCanvas** do JS, eu testo esse resultado da query, e ele é um array preenchido com valores...

Por que ele chega vazio para a função **formaCanvas()** do JS? Onde eu estou errando?
Função Javascript que contém a Ajax call:

```
function formaQueryConta(cpf){

        var numConta= jsonDtContasCliente[(document.getElementById("listaContas").value)-1];
        var parms = "&cpf="+cpf+"&conta="+numConta;
        ajaxCall("Persistencia.php?action=buscaConta" +parms, formaCanvas);

    }
```

Tudo certo na função acima.

Função AjaxCall:

```
function ajaxCall(stringCall, callback){
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest;

    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (httpRequest.readyState === 4) {
            if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
              callback(httpRequest.responseText);

            }
        }
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', stringCall);
    httpRequest.send();

}
```

Agora o handler de chamadas Ajax no meu .php:

```
if(@$_REQUEST['action'] == 'buscaConta')
    {
     buscaConta();

    }
```

A princípio, tudo certo com o handler.
Agora, a função " buscaConta(); ":

```
 function buscaConta(){

        $con = ConectaDB();
        $cpf = $con->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['cpf']);
        $conta = $con->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['conta']);
        $cpf = extraiSoNumsDeString($cpf); 

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT agencia,conta,saldo FROM contas WHERE dono='$cpf' AND conta='$conta' ORDER BY agencia");
        $retData = Array();
        $x=0;
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){
            print_r($row);
            $retData[] = $row[0];

           }
            $con->close();  
        echo json_encode($retData);

    }
        }
```

Função extraiSoNumsDeString($cpf):

Não tem nada de errado com ela, ela retorna um String de números.

Função organizaResultDaQuery($result); A princípio tudo certo com ela

```
function organizaResultQuery($result){
            $retData = Array();
            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){

            $retData[] = $row[0];
            }

            return $retData;
        }
```

**AQUI APARECE O PROBLEMA: A FUNÇÃO DE CALLBACK DA AJAX CALL QUE RECEBE DO PHP O ARRAY RESULTANTE DA QUERY. O ARRAY CHEGA AQUI VAZIO...**

Nela, eu simplesmente imprimo na tela o resultado da query.:

```
function formaCanvas(res){

    console.log("Retorno da busca completa da conta: " +res);
}
```

A tabela buscada no mySQL:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Perdi quase uma hora debugando e não consigo arrumar. Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Não é só fazer `$retData[] = array('agencia' => $row[0], 'conta' => $row[1], 'saldo' => $row[2])`?

Comment: Pior que não. Porque todo o conteúdo de row está na primeira posição do array.

Comment: Eu já tentei :(

Comment: E o que, literalmente, tem na primeira posição?

Comment: Um array que contém o resultado da query.

Comment: Você não tá confundindo `$row` com `$result`, talvez?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78395/discussion-between-marcelo-uchimura-and-lucas-pletsch).

Comment: @MarceloUchimura. Eu consegui acertar essa parte do php, mas na função formaCanvas(res) eu recebo apenas isso:  []

Comment: Tem certeza que você tá passando um CPF e uma conta para os quais tem dado?

Comment: Sim. Se eu dou um echo na função buscaConta, depois disso: $conta = $con->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['conta']);
        $cpf = extraiSoNumsDeString($cpf);      Mostra os valores do cpf e conta corretamente.

Comment: então o problema ainda está no `organizaResultQuery()`

Comment: SIm. Agora eu vi que tá. Só está dando certo para a primeira conta da lista de contas do cliente que eu seleciono quando eu vou ver o saldo

Comment: Isto é outra funcionalidade. Tá tudo enrolado agora. vou olhar com calma

Comment: PIOR QUE NÃO.  A linha: $conta = $con->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['conta']);  retorna o número da conta que eu selecionei na lista de contas do cliente corretamente.

Comment: Espera. Achei um problema.